# I can't seem to query my custom post types correctly.

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to display the custom post types that I created on the front page of my website, but I cant seem to get it working. I've found a bunch of other posts on how to do this but still I cant get mine to work. Here is my code.

Post Type Registration Function.

```
function property() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Properties', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Property', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Property Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Property Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'property_type' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'property', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'property', 0 );
```

Custom Taxonomy Registration Function

```
function property_types() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Property Types', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Property Type', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Property Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'Property Type', array( 'property' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'property_types', 0 );
```

My Query.

```
<?php
 $args = array(
      'post_type'         => 'properties',
      'post_status'       => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'    => -1,
      'orderby'           => 'date',
      'order'             => 'DESC',
      'post_parent'       => 0,
      'category__in'      => '61',
      'tax_query' => array(
                       array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'Property Type',
                         'field' => 'slug',
                         'terms' => property,
                       )
                      ),
  );
// Query posts
$prop_query = new wp_query( $args ); ?>
```

I don't quite understand what needs to be assigned to "Field" and to the "Terms" of the tax_query. Maybe thats my issue?

Comment: Ok so I've figured out the reason that the posts aren't displaying is because my taxonomy isn't using categories. So when I try to pull the ID of the category it doesn't work. However when I try to filter by tag, that doesn't work either. Now I need to figure out how I can pull the posts by the "category" that they are under.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

Custom Post Type Registration Function:

```
// I changed the names a bit for security
function ajwerth_property_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Properties', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Property', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Property Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Property Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'property_type' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'property', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ajwerth_property_cpt' );
```

Custom Taxonomy Registration Function:

```
function ajwerth_property_type_ct() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Property Types', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Property Type', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Property Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'property_type', array( 'property' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ajwerth_property_type_ct' );
```

New WP Query:

```
 $args = array(
      'post_type'         => 'property',
      'post_status'       => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'    => -1,
      'orderby'           => 'date',
      'order'             => 'DESC',
      'post_parent'       => 0,
      'tax_query' => array(
                       array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'property_type',
                         'field'    => 'slug',
                         'terms'    => array( 'properties', 'foo' ), // add the terms here
                       )
                     ),
  );

$prop_query = new wp_query( $args );
```

Let me know if you can solve it